# rasterio.mask returns only nan values

Tags: python, mask, rasterio

I want to mask some polygons onto a raster image with rasterio.mask but all I get are nan values. I have checked that they are in the same coordinate system and in GIS the layers overlap. What can be wrong? For my raster image i have used

```
dem = rasterio.open(DEM, crs='EPSG:3006')
```

and my polygons are derived from a dataframe (when i plot them they look alright). But when i try to use mask

```
geom_dem, info = mask (dem, [geom],  crop=True, invert=False, all_touched=False)
```

the result geom_dem becomes:

```
array([[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
    [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
    [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
    ...,
    [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
    [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
    [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)
```

I have checked and there are no element with a value other than nan.

What could be wrong and how is it fixed?

Comment: I little more code will be brilliant...

Comment: Can you include detailed information showing the coordinates/extents of the `dem` and `geom` data.

There's a high chance that something is wrong with the coordinate system/projection, making them either not overlap or be completely different scales.